# How do I update the modules that come with python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I am having trouble with the subprocess module. I am missing the check_output function and I was wondering if there is a way to update/replace this without doing a complete reinstall of python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you can add the function in yourself if necessary (only suggested if you need it for backwards capability).

```
if 'check_output' not in dir(subprocess):
    def check_output(cmd_args, *args, **kwargs):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd_args, *args,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
        out, err = proc.communicate()
        if proc.returncode != 0:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(args)
        return out
    subprocess.check_output = check_output
```

But as that code shows, you can also just write it a little more verbosely and it doesn't operate any differently.

Edit: Copy directly from subprocess module version Python 2.7

```
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
    process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    return output
```

Comment: So that will do the same thing as the original function?

Comment: Effectively yes, I also included a direct copy from the subprocess module from newest version if you wish to use that. Again, I would only use this as a backwards compatibility for existing code. If you are writing new code I would just use Popen and .communicate() on their own.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6 for this project, will this code still work? @CasualDemon

Comment: I updated it with the source from subprocess for 2.7, I have tested it with 2.6 as well and it works.